# Why are some saved pages 'corrupted' when accessed in windows?

Tags: sharing

Ive been learning and using ubuntu alongside windows 10 to learn Linux, slowly back away from windows and also to keep windows offline as much as possible. That also means i save pages and do my downloads/research in Ubuntu.

Both OSs have their own partitions on my main HD, but all my files, folders, work etc are on another internal drive with an NTFS formatting.

I havent had any trouble until today, when a handful of saved webpages and the folder they're in became 'inaccessible and corrupted' in windows. All other downloads still work fine, most pages are fine, just these particular ones. Ubuntu has no trouble.

Ive checked to make sure there are no illegal characters in the names, but i cant even access the file their in.

The most technical idea my brain has is windows has somehow started recognising that it has to share the computer with another OS and is making a fuss... I really dont know.

Any help or ideas appreciated. Thank you

Comment: When you say "but i cant even access the file their in." you mean the "folder they're in" right?

Comment: Linux uses UTF-8 Char encoding for files, Windows use US-ASCII Char encoding for files. 
Since you mostly want to deploy websites on a Linux server, use an editor where you can set your encoding under Windows and work with UTF-8 encoding under Windows.

Comment: Here, some Resource to get to know what exactly your problem is: http://superuser.com/questions/294219/what-are-the-differences-between-linux-and-windows-txt-files-unicode-encoding

Comment: Ah yes, i meant folder sorry. Thanks for the links guys looking into it now. Mondjunge, when you say use an editor to set my encoding, do you mean theres an editor i can use to save my webpages/work to be usable on both OS?